# Jasmine unit tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Hi I am new to jasmine.

Can any body suggest to write test case for this code which is in AngularJS

```
$('#issueDateSpan').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#datetimepickerIssue').data('DateTimePicker').show();
});
```

Comment: What do you want to verify? That the DateTimePicker is displayed?

Comment: yes i need to test in jasmine

Comment: i want to show test coverage in karma

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to tests that the DateTimePicker is displayed.

Have you tried something like:

```
describe('visibility', function() {
     it('DateTimePicker is displayed', function() {
      expect(element(by.id('datetimepickerIssue').is(':visible')).toBe(true); 
      }); 
    });
```

or

```
describe('visibility', function() {
         it('DateTimePicker is displayed', function() {
            expect($('#DateTimePicker').is(':visible')).toBe(true);
          }); 
        });
```